# VBA for vlookup referencing previous spreadsheet

Tags: vba, variables, vlookup

I'm trying to set up VBA code that will create a new `vlookup` formula that references the previous spreadsheet whenever I create a new spreadsheet. Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim PS As Worksheet

Set PS = ActiveSheet.Previous

Range("L5").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2]," & PS.Name & "C[-2]:C[-1],2,FALSE),""N/A"")"
```

I've researched this quite a bit, but I've never seen anyone try to set a variable as `ActiveSheet.Previous`. In other solutions I've seen, it's always been a fixed sheet.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct would this work for you?

```
Set PS = thisworkbook.worksheets(activesheet.index - 1)
```

It'll throw an error if the activesheet has an index of 1

Comment: Actually, I found out I was really close.  I left out the normal formatting that Excel automatically adds to the formula when you reference a different worksheet.  Here is the code that worked:

Range("L5").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'" & PS.Name & "'!C[-2]:C[-1],2,FALSE),""N/A"")"

I just needed to put '" & PS.Name & "'! instead of " & PS.Name & "